# How to hide a div on a page when that page has been created by a specific user role

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have wordpress wedding website where vendors list their businesses and users can contact them directly but some listings were created by the admin (like the below link). How can I hide an element (the messaging element) based on user role - I need to hide the contact div for the listings created by the admin. The class for the element I am trying to hide is "new-listing-sidebar".
I have seen many posts about trying to hide the element FOR users i.e. if a user role is "editor" then a div is hidden, but none about how to hide a div on a page that has been created by a specific user role (or user category) via their listings.

https://nearly-weds.co.uk/item/amazon-gift-list/

Is this even possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is include the role name as a class in the body tag (need to modify theme's header.php and functions.php slightly probably).
Then it would be easy using CSS to control who sees what.

```html
<body class="<? echo wp_get_current_user()->roles[0]; ?>">...
</body>
```

This would result in `<body class="administrator">` if you're logged in. Otherwise `roles` might be empty array so make sure you check that case.

then in CSS it should be easy to (for example)

```css
.admin-only {
    display: none;
}

body.administrator .admin-only {
    display: block;
}
```

Be aware that this only hides the content *visually* and not from search engines or "advanced" users indeed.

Comment: That's a nice workaround. In reality the content still exists and is visible in the HTML, however.